# Rowwise extract data between two strings

Tags: r

I have a data.table and I want to extract data between two strings.

E.g given

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Id=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
                      "B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
                 Date=c("2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19",
                    "2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-19","2019-07-21","2019-07-21","2019-07-23","2019-07-23"),               
                 City=c("Chicago","Nashville","Phoenix","Seattle","Chicago","Miami","Houston","Phoenix",
                     "Chicago","Denver","Alaska","Phoenix","Montgomery","Chicago","Phoenix","Harrisburg"))
```

If I want to extract data between "Chicago" and "Phoenix" according to Id, Date

I hope return

```
    Id     Date        City
1   A   2019-07-19   Chicago
2   A   2019-07-19   Nashville
3   A   2019-07-19   Phoenix     #1~3 of the original data
4   A   2019-07-19   Chicago
5   A   2019-07-19   Miami
6   A   2019-07-19   Houston
7   A   2019-07-19   Phoenix     #5~8 of the original data
8   B   2019-07-19   Chicago     #9~12 of the original data
9   B   2019-07-19   Denver
10  B   2019-07-19   Alaska
11  B   2019-07-19   Phoenix
```

In the original data, I have multiple different Id, Date, City

So I hope that I can get the data range according to Id, date, and extract.

I don't know if I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy, but also pretty faulty if you have some unexpected hiccups in data (like you haven't observed a Phoenix instance yet, or your data starts without a Chicago).

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
keep <- mapply(seq, which(DT$City == 'Chicago'), which(DT$City == 'Phoenix'))
```

And you can subset the table with:

```
DT[unlist(keep), ]
```

For the following output;

```
> DT[unlist(keep), ]
   Id       Date      City
1   A 2019-07-19   Chicago
2   A 2019-07-19 Nashville
3   A 2019-07-19   Phoenix
5   A 2019-07-19   Chicago
6   A 2019-07-19     Miami
7   A 2019-07-19   Houston
8   A 2019-07-19   Phoenix
9   B 2019-07-19   Chicago
10  B 2019-07-19    Denver
11  B 2019-07-19    Alaska
12  B 2019-07-19   Phoenix
14  C 2019-07-21   Chicago
15  C 2019-07-23   Phoenix
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is the best solution but, the first thing I thought by using `base R`,

```
data1 <- which(DT$City %in% c("Chicago"))
data2 <- which(DT$City %in% c("Phoenix"))
logic <- (data2- data1)>1
data1 <-data1[logic]
data2 <-data2[logic]

myrows <- unlist(lapply(1:length(data1),function(i) {seq(data1[i],data2[i])}))

DT[myrows ,]
```

gives,

```
    Id       Date      City
 1:  A 2019-07-19   Chicago
 2:  A 2019-07-19 Nashville
 3:  A 2019-07-19   Phoenix
 4:  A 2019-07-19   Chicago
 5:  A 2019-07-19     Miami
 6:  A 2019-07-19   Houston
 7:  A 2019-07-19   Phoenix
 8:  B 2019-07-19   Chicago
 9:  B 2019-07-19    Denver
10:  B 2019-07-19    Alaska
11:  B 2019-07-19   Phoenix
```

Comment: @KenChen I don't understand. You were asking **between** the Chicago and Phoenix and you cancelled out the data if there is no state between those two. So that is why you ended up with 11 row data. This answer was the only one includes 11 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat nasty workaround

```
library(dplyr)
DT <- DT %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(query = as.numeric(stringr::str_detect(City, "Chicago|Phoenix")))

# Sanity check, we should have pairs
candidates <- which(DT$query == 1)
len_cand <- length(candidates)
len_cand %% 2 == 0 # should return TRUE
```

Now we can construct indices and create sequential subset indices from the odd (read first) candidate, to the even (read last) candidate that we matched.

```
odd_candidates <- candidates[seq(1, len_cand, 2)]
even_candidates <-candidates[seq(2, len_cand, 2)]

li <- list()
for(i in 1:length(odd_candidates)){
  li <- append(li, seq(odd_candidates[i], even_candidates[i], 1))
}

DT[unlist(li), ]
```

This is the output (I kept the query as control)

```
   Id    Date       City      query
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
 1 A     2019-07-19 Chicago       1
 2 A     2019-07-19 Nashville     0
 3 A     2019-07-19 Phoenix       1
 4 A     2019-07-19 Chicago       1
 5 A     2019-07-19 Miami         0
 6 A     2019-07-19 Houston       0
 7 A     2019-07-19 Phoenix       1
 8 B     2019-07-19 Chicago       1
 9 B     2019-07-19 Denver        0
10 B     2019-07-19 Alaska        0
11 B     2019-07-19 Phoenix       1
12 C     2019-07-21 Chicago       1
13 C     2019-07-23 Phoenix       1
```

There's potential to have `City1` and `City2` as arguments of a function.

Answer (score 0):

While this solution account for a dataset without an equal amount of "Chicago" followed by by "Phoenix". You might try this. First add a rownumber column and determine which ranges you want to extract, then extract them and remove the rownumber column again:

```
DT$Rownumber <- seq.int(nrow(DT))
rowsChicago <- which(DT$City == "Chicago")
rowsPhoenix <- which(DT$City == "Phoenix")

range <- data.frame(rowsChicago, rowsPhoenix)

DT <- DT[Rownumber %inrange% range, 1:3]
```